# C# Returning words in a string that contains another string

Tags: c#, string

Hello I'm a beginner at C# I want to know how I can return the words in a string that contain another string.

for example:

```
string s1 = "This is a string"
string s2 = "is"
```

I know I can use the following code to return the whole string:

```
        if (s1.Contains(s2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} does not contain {1}",s1,s2);
        }
```

but how can I return only the words that contain the second string?

so:

```
Result: This is
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at string.IndexOf ands string.Substring

Comment: What if s1 contains multiples of s2?

Comment: Why is the resut "this is" and not e.g. "is a"?

Answer (score 3):

A very simple and quick solution, assuming you define 'word' as pieces of your string being delimited by a `<space>`.

```
var containingWords = s1.Split(' ').Where(word => word.Contains(s2));
```

Comment: Documentation for the used methods: [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split), [IEnumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) and [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains)

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = "This is a string";
        string s2 = "is";
        int _index = s1.IndexOf(s2);
        if(_index > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s1.Substring(_index, _index + s2.Length));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to split the string into words; assuming that word is a *sequence of letters or apostrophes*, you can do it with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
   var words = Regex
     .Matches(s1, @"[\p{L}']+")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(match => match.Value);
```

However, you don't want *all* the words; you have to filter them, say, with a help of *Linq* `Where`:

```
   string[] words = Regex
     .Matches(s1, @"[\p{L}']+")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(match => match.Value)
     .Where(word => word.Contains(s2))
     .ToArray();
```

You can `Join` all the words found into a single string:

```
   string result = string.Join(" ", Regex
     .Matches(s1, @"[\p{L}']+")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(match => match.Value)
     .Where(word => word.Contains(s2)));
```